# How to set maximum size of JFrame?

Tags: java

There is the following code:

```
double gridWidth=columnNumber*(IMAGE_WIDTH_NORMAL+10)+(columnNumber+2)*10;
double screenWidth=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()*0.8;
screenWidth=(gridWidth>=screenWidth) ? screenWidth : gridWidth;

double gridHeight=(rules.size()+2)*(IMAGE_HEIGHT_NORMAL+10)+rules.size()*20+(rules.size()+2)*10;
double screenHeight=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()*0.8;
screenHeight=(gridHeight>=screenHeight) ? screenHeight : gridHeight;

setSize((int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight);
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
setLocation(screenSize.width/2-getWidth()/2, screenSize.height/2-getHeight()/2);
setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int)gridWeight, (int)gridHeight));
setVisible(true);
```

This code does the following thing: calculates preferred width and height of frame, and if the size bigger then I want (80% of width and height), then application sets another size; but I want to allow user to click by "full screen" icon on the jframe in order to maximize jframe for preferred size (setMaximumSize() method), but it code doesn't work! Always a windows maximizes to full screen of my laptop! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but I suggest using

[java.awt.Window#setBounds(int, int, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

to set the location and size of a JFrame.

```
 int x = screenSize.width/2-getWidth()/2;
 int y = screenSize.height/2-getHeight()/2;
 int width = (int)gridWeight;
 int height = (int)gridHeight);
 setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

To maximize a JFrame I suggest using

[java.awt.Frame#setExtendedState(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29)

like this

```
setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this :

_mainDialog.setBounds(rectangle);

_mainDialog.setExtendedState(windowsState);

**Example** :

```
        addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                int oldState = e.getOldState();
                int newState = e.getNewState();

                if ((oldState & JFrame.ICONIFIED) == 0 && (newState & JFrame.ICONIFIED) != 0) {
                    setMainDialogRectangle(minRectangle, JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
                else if ((oldState & JFrame.ICONIFIED) != 0 && (newState & JFrame.ICONIFIED) == 0) {
                    setMainDialogRectangle(minRectangle, JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
                else if ((e.getNewState() & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    setMainDialogRectangle(maxRectangle, JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
                else if ((oldState & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) != 0 && (newState & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == 0) {
                    setMainDialogRectangle(medRectangle, JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
            }
        });
```